# Finding and first and middle initials in a list of names in python

Tags: python, list

In a list of names(3 full names) I need to extract the first and middle initials with the last name in full and return all this as a string...Here is what I have tried but I keep getting just one name and not the three when I iterate...Pls help ..new to python,and this is driving me bunkers..
My code below:

```py
def fancy_me(name_string):

    name = ', '.join(name_string)
    name_list = name.split()
    name_sublist = name_list[:3]
    name_sublist2 = name_list[3:6]
    name_sublist3 = name_list[-3:]
    new_namelist = [name_sublist, name_sublist2, name_sublist3]
    for x in new_namelist:
        new_list = []
        first = (x[0][0])
        mid = (x[1][0])
        last = (x[2])
    return first + ' .' + mid + '. ' + last

print(fancy_me(["First Middle Last", "David Andrew Joyner", "George P Burdell"]))
```

my output: `G .P. Burdell`

Desired output: `F. M. Last, D. A. Joyner, G. P. Burdell`

Comment: What is `name_string`? Wasn't that parameter rather supposed to be `names: list[str]`? Doesn't it make much more sense to process each `name` in that list individually, and only `', '.join` the results at the end?

Comment: You aren’t returning a list, so I’m nt sure why you’re surprised you only get a single name

Comment: @manfred, name_string, is the parameter name for the list of strings... the function returns

Comment: @Manfred...it is all making sense, will try that now..Thanks!

Comment: you need to put `new_list` defining out of the loop and then append to `new_list` for each one. Then return the `new_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. First, you are joining at the wrong time - you want to do the comma join at the end rather than the beginning. This is getting in the way of the splitting you're doing. Then it looks like you have wrong expectiations of how Python will deal with the inputs above your loop. It will not do any looping over the inputs automatically.

I'd break out the two different functions as follows:

```
def initialize(name):
    first, middle, last = name.split()  # note this assumes all names will only be three parts

    return f"{first[0]}. {middle[0]}. {last}"

def fancy_me(namelist):
    return ", ".join(initialize(name) for name in namelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate the assumption in @chthonicdaemon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69515254/13134095) that all names consist of three parts, you can adapt the solution in the following way:

```py
def initialize(name: str) -> str:
    parts = name.split()
    return ". ".join(part[0] for part in parts) + parts[-1][1:]

def fancy_me(namelist: list[str]) -> str:
    return ", ".join(initialize(name) for name in namelist)
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, both codes made sense and returned the desired output. Great community on here, will continue to learn and not give up! Many Thanks!!