# Creating emails while accounting for two first names when using input()

Tags: python, list, function, input

My code below works as long as all of the student's name consists of only two names - ex. Julie Andrews. But, when generating the student's emails, I'm trying to account for the students who have two first names - ex. Mary Jane Stewart. I want it to output something like MJStewart123@gmail.org, vs. what my current code will print, which is MJane123@gmail.com - totally ignoring the student's last name.

After hours of researching Google, I have tried updating my *create_emails* fx to change my original variable *first_last = name.split(" ")* to something like **first, middle, last = name.split(" ")** *or* **first_last = name.split(" ", 2)** while also, respectively, updating the line utilizing the attribute .append from its original to **student_emails.append(first_last[0][0] + first_last[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515169/finding-and-first-and-middle-initials-in-a-list-of-names-in-python) + first_last[2]+ last_three_sid + "@gmail.com")** *or* **student_emails.append(first[0] + middle[0] + last + last_three_sid + "@gmail.com")**. All attempts have obviously returned some form of an error...

The attached Stack Overflow article is the closest thing I could find whose logic might be applicable to what I'm trying to accomplish here, specifically the comment by Manfred, but in reading it, I don't know how to apply what they've done to my program... because I don't quite understand what it is that I'm reading... since I'm such a newbie at all this. I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

```
student_names = []

def create_names():
  count = 1
  while count <= 5:
    name = input("Enter student name, please. ")
    student_names.append(name)
    count += 1 
create_names()

import random

student_ids = []

def create_ids():
  student_id = random.randint(111111,999999)
  return student_id

def create_id_list():
  for name in student_names:
    student_ids.append(create_ids())
create_id_list()

student_emails = []

def create_emails():
  for name in student_names:
    first_last = name.split(" ")
    sid = str(student_ids[student_names.index(name)])
    len_sid = len(sid)
    last_three_sid = sid[len_sid-3:len_sid]
    student_emails.append(first_last[0][0] + first_last[1] + last_three_sid + "@gmail.com") #ignores last index if one is provided.

create_emails()

def student_info():
  for name in student_names:
    name_pos = student_names.index(name)
    print("\n" + "name: " + name)
    print("id: " + str(student_ids[name_pos]))
    print("email: " + student_emails[name_pos])
student_info()
```

Finding and first and middle initials in a list of names in python

Comment: Why don't you simply do `names = name.split(" ")` which will result in `names` being a list and then you can simply create email by `"_".join(names) + "_" + str(last_three_sid)`. This should account for however many names they have.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your statement "create email by "_".join(names) + "_" + str(last_three_sid)." Where exactly am I putting that?

Comment: It goes in the `create_emails` function where you're appending a new email to the list of emails.

Comment: I updated my ' student_emails.append(first_last[0][0] + first_last[1] + last_three_sid + "@gmail.com"' to be 'student_emails.join(names) + str(last_three_sid) + "@gmail.com"' and got the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join.' And, I changed my variable 'first_last' > 'names,' as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this I guess:

```
student_names = []

def create_names():
    count = 1
    while count <= 5:
        name = input("Enter student name, please. ")
        student_names.append(name)
        count += 1 
create_names()

import random

student_ids = []

def create_ids():
    student_id = random.randint(111111,999999)
    return student_id

def create_id_list():
    for name in student_names:
        student_ids.append(create_ids())
create_id_list()

student_emails = []

def create_emails():
    for name in student_names:
        email_name = ""
        first_last = name.split(" ")
        for i, v in enumerate(first_last):
            if i > len(first_last)-2:
                break
            email_name+=v[0]
        email_name = email_name+first_last[-1]
        sid = str(student_ids[student_names.index(name)])
        len_sid = len(sid)
        last_three_sid = sid[len_sid-3:len_sid]
        student_emails.append(email_name + last_three_sid + "@gmail.com") #ignores last index if one is provided.

create_emails()

def student_info():
    for name in student_names:
        name_pos = student_names.index(name)
        print("\n" + "name: " + name)
        print("id: " + str(student_ids[name_pos]))
        print("email: " + student_emails[name_pos])
student_info()
```

Result:

```
Enter student name, please. Julie Andrews
Enter student name, please. Mary Jane Stewart
Enter student name, please. Jack Hendricks
Enter student name, please. Maria Basset Juliett
Enter student name, please. Marco Hansen

name: Julie Andrews
id: 742536
email: JAndrews536@gmail.com

name: Mary Jane Stewart
id: 823274
email: MJStewart274@gmail.com

name: Jack Hendricks
id: 590875
email: JHendricks875@gmail.com

name: Maria Basset Juliett
id: 982168
email: MBJuliett168@gmail.com

name: Marco Hansen
id: 671240
email: MHansen240@gmail.com
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! It's beautiful. Now I'll have something to study tomorrow, to try to understand what's exactly happening within your new changes. :) "v in enumerate" is new to me, and my brain is questioning what's happening in that if statement you made.... Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: @RenelynCruz No problem, feel free to accept my answer. Also your name reminds me of someone from the Philippines, my wife is from the Philippines and your names seem a bit the same. :-)

Comment: LOL. Yes, I'm actually filipino. Trying to get into the Software Coding world. 

Answer (score 0):

The code is too redundant and could be implemented with some simpler structures.

1. name construction can use split combined with join function
2. storage can also use dictionaries to store multiple information about the same object, compared to multiple lists so more concise and efficient
   The code itself is not a big problem, mainly the syntax structure requires more skilled,let's encourage each other in our endeavours
   try this:

```
import random

info = []

# You can use for loop if you already know how many times it will loop
for i in range(5):
    name = input("Enter student name, please:")  # get name
    student_id = random.randint(111111, 999999)  # get id
    name_structure = name.split()
    email = "{name_abbr}{last_name}{sid}@gmail.com".format(
        name_abbr="".join([item[0] for item in name_structure[:-1]]),   # Generate initials
        last_name=name_structure[-1],   # Generate the last part of the name
        sid=str(student_id)[-3:]    # Generate the id in the mailbox
    )
    info.append({"name": name, "id": student_id, "email": email})       # Store to the list, or print directly

# Print Information
for item in info:
    print("name:", item["name"])
    print("id:", item["id"])
    print("email:", item["email"])
    print()
```

Comment: I do agree that this structure is a lot simpler, but as someone who is really new to coding, there are a lot of parts in what you wrote that I would need some help in understanding... But thank you for giving me something new to study. :)

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I didn't write it concisely enough, but actually the contents inside are all basic python modules, including list, dictionary, string, format, join, random, input, split, and I'm also a learner

Comment: I hope we can we friends who learn together! :) Of those, I'm not overly familiar with dictionary & join. I've heard of format... but I've yet to totally grasp exactly how it works.

Comment: Of course, feel free to exchange and learn

Comment: So, with the help of Thonny, I now understand this code better. But, I was hoping you could clarify for me why you chose to use -1 in the variables for name_abbr and last_name, instead of +1. They both accomplish the same result... at least, from what I understand. 

Whereas, with the variable sid, I could understand using -3, as I'm seeing that as telling the computer to "drop the first 3 numbers, print from there to the end of the string.

Comment: I don't quite understand the naming style in your country, so I just follow the example of your title to understand the name composition

Comment: for example, the name consists of three parts, like this: Mary Jane Stewart, after using the split method name_structure = ["Mary", "Jane", "Stewart"], I divide the email into three parts: " {name_abbr}{last_name}{sid}@gmail.com"

Comment: name_abbr is the abbreviated name with the first letter of the name except the last name, last_name is the last name of the name, sid is the last three digits of student_id

Comment: so in the construction of name_abbr abbr is used when constructing name_abbr[:-1], which means that it does not contain the last item, and [-1] is used when constructing last_name, which means that only the last item is obtained, and ***List Comprehensions*** is used in the content: [item[0] for item in name_structure[:-1]], which can be understood, which means that using name_structure[:-1], which means building a new list with the first element of each data item in name_structure[:-1]